# How to prevent to tshark to create temp files under /tmp?

Tags: linux, tshark

I want to run followed command:

```
tshark  -l >  some.txt
```

As you see I write `stdout` to `some.txt` file.

But I get under `/tmp` folder temp files named `etherXXXX*` and these files can increase to  1-2G during 1 hour.

From `tshark man` I found to use `-b option`.

So I wrote:

```
tshark -b filesize:1024 -b files:5  -l >  some.txt
```

and got error: `tshark: Maximum capture file size specified, but capture isn't being saved to a file.`

From `tshark.c` code i found to use `-w` flag

```
tshark -b filesize:1024 -b files:5  -l -w >  some.txt
```

Now no files have been created under `/tmp` but some.txt file now bin file and i cant open it. Because `-w` flag make it like with `cap` extension. :(

How can I handle temp files?

BTW, `some.txt` file content was:

```
  0.118166 1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /services/client/client.php?cnc=13 HTTP/1.1
  0.136235 1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /services/client/clsWebClient.php HTTP/1.1
  0.271442 1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /services/client/client.php?cnc=13 HTTP/1.1
  1.190018 1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2  HTTP GET /services/client/clsWebClient.php HTTP/1.1
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the [`-w <outfile>`](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html#w_outfile) option to redirect touput to a file

in this case (without output redirection):

```
tshark -b filesize:1024 -b files:5  -l -w some.txt
```

The created file(s) will contain the binary data from the dump. You can later analyze this using [`-r <infile>`](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html#r_infile) to read the file and produce text output.

Comment: this wouldn't affect the file written to --temp-dir by dumpcap